# Why is qemu-kvm needed in Debian Wheezy when running qemu with "-enable-kvm" option?

Tags: kvm, qemu

I have a *HP Compaq 8200* PC with *Intel i5* CPU. I have enabled VT-x in BIOS:

[image: HP Compaq 8200 BIOS]

..and CPU supports VT-x as it has `vmx` flag present in `/proc/cpuinfo`. I have loaded the `kvm` LKM:

```
root@VM-host:~# modprobe -v kvm
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko 
root@LS15-C-LAB-VM-host:~# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   239136  0 
root@VM-host:~#
```

..but if I executed `qemu` with `-enable-kvm` option, it complained that:

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
No accelerator found!
```

`/dev/kvm` file was is indeed missing:

```
root@VM-host:~# ls -l /dev/kvm
ls: cannot access /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
root@VM-host:~#
```

Once I installed the `qemu-kvm` package, I was able to start the `qemu` with `-enable-kvm` option. As I had understood, `kvm` support is merged into `qemu` and all that is needed for `qemu` is kvm LKM. Why is qemu-kvm package needed in Debian Wheezy when running qemu with "-enable-kvm" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qemu-kvm` was indeed merged into QEMU, but that happened in version 1.3. Debian Wheezy ships QEMU 1.1.2 which still needs `qemu-kvm` for KVM support.

Comment: I see. What kind of functionality does `qemu-kvm` provide? Interaction between `qemu` and `kvm` LKM?

Comment: That's right, it provides hardware-supported virtualisation in QEMU using KVM support in the kernel.